# Why do I get build errors Error: MSB3491 and Warning: MSB3101 after copying Visual Studio 2022 solution onto a new computer?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a .NetCore C# project built in Visual Studio 2022.
It builds and runs correctly on the original machine: "LaptopA."

When I attempt to copy to folder structure to new machine "MachineB," I get a lot of errors regarding **csproj.AssemblyReference.cache**.

**Here is an example of the error message I am seeing:**

> Error   MSB3491 Could not write lines to file
> "obj\Debug\net7.0\SampleProject.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access
> to the path '\LaptopA\croot\Dev
> Projects\SampleProjectFolder\obj\Debug\net7.0\SampleProject.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt'
> is denied.
> Warning   MSB3101 Could not write state file "obj\Debug\net7.0\SampleProject.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache".
> Access to the path
> '\LaptopA\croot\SampleProjectFolder\SampleProject\obj\Debug\net7.0\SampleProject.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache'
> is denied.     SampleProject  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    2352
> Error MSB4018 The "GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig" task failed
> unexpectedly. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> '\LaptopA\croot\SampleProjectFolder\SampleProject\obj\Debug\net7.0\SampleProject.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'
> is denied.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
> maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
> mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
> share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
> secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
> Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
> FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean
> useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    at
> System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean
> checkHost)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean
> append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)    at
> System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents,
> Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)    at
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig.WriteMSBuildEditorConfig()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() SampleProject   C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets    190

I have no idea why it's attempting to access/write to location on the machine that I originally copied from. I searched through all files located in my solution and found no reference to "**LaptopA**."

Is there something missing here or something that I need to reset either in a configuration file or project properties in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Delete the obj and bin directories and recompile?

Comment: Or, start with `Build` -> `Clean`.  If that doesn't work, try @gunr2171's suggestion

Comment: @gunr2171/@Flydog57 - Did build clean, the recursively deleted all the bin and obj folders in my solution. I still get the same error. Where is that machine name getting cached?

Comment: Forgot to mention that build errors were predicated with Error MSB4018 The "GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig" task failed unexpectedly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241729/new-generated-generatedmsbuildeditorconfig-file-since-recent-upgrade

Comment: What's the version of VS2022 on your Machine B? An idea to try: upgrate the version of VS2022.